# Count number of subsequences within a sequence with max allowed events in between

Tags: python, algorithm, sequence

Given a main sequence of events (e.g., `A->B->A->B->B`), a subsequence (`A->B`), and a max allowed events in between (`n`), I would like to count the number of subsequences (`N`) within the main sequence.

For example,

`N=2` for `n=0` (First A -> First B, Second A -> Second B)

`N=3` for `n=1` (First A -> First B, Second A -> Second B, Second A -> Third B)

`N=4` for `n=2` (First A -> First B, Second A -> Second B, Second A -> Third B, First A -> Second B)

`N=5` for `n=3` (First A -> First B, Second A -> Second B, Second A -> Third B, First A -> Second B, First A -> Third B)

Is there an efficient algorithm for this problem? The main sequence for my problem can be long and I have many subsequences to count for.

Comment: In a general case you can't do better than linear (w.r.t. of the main sequence length). OTOH, a sliding window is a linear solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may probably get some results with regular expressions, but it depends on how complicated are your event definitions.
Alternatively you may go with something like

```
result = [(first,first+steps+1)
          for steps in range(len(seq)-1) for first in range(len(seq)-steps-1)
          if seq[first]==target[0] and seq[first+steps+1]==target[1]]

>>> result
[(0, 1), (2, 3), (2, 4), (0, 3), (0, 4)]
```

Although I don't know if it would be efficient enough for large datasets